# running the model by the def function

Tags: python, model

I have a set of 3 gredi estimators that call them that way, but I don't like them and I would like to call them through loops. But my function doesn't work.

```
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV


##==============================================================================

RFC1 = GridSearchCV(estimator=RFC,
                      param_grid = params_RFC1,
                      cv=cv_method,
                      verbose=1,
                      scoring = 'roc_auc') 

##==============================================================================

RFC2 = GridSearchCV(estimator=RFC,
                      param_grid = params_RFC2,
                      cv=cv_method,
                      verbose=1,
                      scoring = 'roc_auc') 
##==============================================================================

RFC3 = GridSearchCV(estimator=RFC,
                      param_grid = params_RFC3,
                      cv=cv_method,
                      verbose=1,
                      scoring = 'roc_auc') 
##==============================================================================
```

Where I make a mistake and I don't know where

```
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV

global model

def model(estimator,param_grid,model):
    model = GridSearchCV(estimator=estimator,
                      param_grid = params,
                      cv=cv_method,
                      verbose=1,
                      scoring = 'roc_auc') 
    return model
```

Comment: What exactly does not work?

Comment: Exactly when after substituting the value for this defined function I should get the model. I can then enter the name of this model in any line and should report it to me. Instead, he reports a mistake to me.

Comment: And what is the error message?

Comment: NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-43-7112861a8fb1> in <module>
----> 1 model(RFC,params_RFC2,RFC2)

NameError: name 'RFC2' is not defined

Comment: Can you share how you call your function please, it seems that RFC2 is not defined before calling the function.

Answer (score 0):

```
    from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier

    RFC = RandomForestClassifier()

    #Cross validation

    from sklearn.model_selection import RepeatedStratifiedKFold

    cv_method = RepeatedStratifiedKFold(n_splits=5,            
                                        n_repeats=3,          
                                        random_state=999)
    params_RFC2 = {
     'max_depth': [2, 3],
     'min_samples_leaf': [3, 4],
     'n_estimators':  [500,1000]}

gs_RFC = GridSearchCV(estimator=RFC,
                      param_grid = params_RFC,
                      cv=cv_method,
                      verbose=1,
                      scoring = 'roc_auc') 

    gs_RFC.fit(Data, target)
```